# On CPU cache access

Tags: cpu-cache

I decided to experiment with the code examples from the paper *[What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/) ([PDF](http://ftp.linux.org.ua/pub/docs/developer/general/cpumemory.pdf))*, and saw a different result from section 6.2.

The programs are doing matrix multiplications, I have made a little change and put them at https://github.com/herberteuler/cpumemory.

In the paper, it is said that the optimization from `matrix1.c` to `matrix2.c`, by transposing the second matrix, could save about 76.6% of cpu cycles (section 6.2.1, page 50):

```
             Original      Transposed
Cycles    16,765,297,870  3,922,373,010
Relative       100%           23.4%
```

But on my node, the result is very different from the above list.

This is my kernel and CPU information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux herberteuler 3.9-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.9.8-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0xa07
cpu MHz         : 2401.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips        : 4788.33
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0xa07
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips        : 4788.33
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

And this is the result of executing `matrix1` and `matrix2`:

```
$ ./matrix1
cpu cycles: 18071621964
$ ./matrix2
cpu cycles: 15716582775
```

Why don't I see the huge reduction of CPU cycles in `matrix2`, as expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends what the matrix transposition algorithm you use and if you added the execution cycles for transposition of the matrix.

Comment: Have you considered maybe showing us those "little changes" you made?

Comment: AMD and Intel might have entirely different profiles here.

Comment: compiled with ...? (_optimization?!_)

Comment: Cache-optimized algorithms tend to be very sensitive to the cache hierarchy you actually have - an algorithm written to work well with 128K of L1 and 1MB of L2 will perform very differently when run on a system with 64K of L1, 512K of L2 and 3MB of L3... It's hard to write a truly generic cache-optimal algorithm.

Comment: @jalf: By "little changes" I mean adding the `main` function to make them run, adding result check codes to make them correct etc, the core code isn't changed.

Comment: @twalberg: Would you like to elaborate on what I should do if I want to see the expected result on my node?  Pointers to background knowledges are appreciated.

Comment: That's not an easy question to answer. Your best bet would be to 1) make sure you understand the logic behind everything in the paper you read, 2) follow the same methodology used in that paper to optimize your algorithms for your specific system. The biggest gain comes from making sure that the entire data set handled in the innermost part of your loop can be comfortably contained entirely in your L1 cache. Then use tiles/stripes to handle a larger problem in suitably-sized pieces.

Comment: @user2595776 the point is that you took some codes which gave result A, made a change, and now you get result B. In order to explain *why* you now get result B instead of A, **show us exactly what you changed**

Comment: The code seems fine (i.e. - should show prove the point that the article is trying to make here about spatial locality). Please also write the parameters you used (matrix sizes), if they're too small the benefit could be gone. I'm also suspecting that stride prefetchers could eat up the benefits, but it's too early to judge.